# VBA splitting or shortening a procedure

Tags: vba, excel

My procedure is too long so I want to split it into subs or shorten the code somehow, but I'm having trouble doing that. A piece of the code:

```
Sub Inlezen()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim BookingDate As Date
Dim CancellationDate As Date
Dim BookedPax As Long
Dim BookingClass As String
Dim PointOfSale As String
Dim Origin As String
Dim Destination As String
Dim Accept As String

InputFile = "PathToFile"
Open InputFile For Input As #1
row_number = 0
Line Input #1, Dummy1

Do Until EOF(1)

Line Input #1, LineFromFile
LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")

BookingDate = LineItems(0)
CancellationDate = LineItems(1)
BookedPax = LineItems(2)
BookingClass = LineItems(3)
PointOfSale = LineItems(4)
Origin = LineItems(5)
Destination = LineItems(6)

If (BookingClass = "EL" And PointOfSale = "ES" And Origin = "FCO" And Destination = "AMS" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PrijsKlasses").Range("D2") > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PrijsKlasses").Range("G2") And CancellationDate = "" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B65") < (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B15") + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B73"))) Then
    Accept = "Yes"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B33") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B33") + BookedPax

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = BookingDate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = CancellationDate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 2).Value = BookedPax
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 4).Value = BookingClass
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 5).Value = PointOfSale
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 6).Value = Origin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 7).Value = Destination

ElseIf (BookingClass = "EH" And PointOfSale = "ES" And Origin = "FCO" And Destination = "AMS" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PrijsKlasses").Range("D3") > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PrijsKlasses").Range("G2") And CancellationDate = "" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B65") < (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B15") + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B73"))) Then
    Accept = "Yes"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("C33") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("C33") + BookedPax

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = BookingDate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = CancellationDate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 2).Value = BookedPax
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 4).Value = BookingClass
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 5).Value = PointOfSale
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 6).Value = Origin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 7).Value = Destination
```

There are many more of the same `ElseIf`s. Any idea's on how to make this shorter?

Comment: When you wrote this code it is almost certain that you did massive amounts of copy-pasting, with minor editing. The blocks which are copy-pasted could be abstracted to a sub or function, with the edited parts corresponding to parameters for the sub/function. In general -- get rid of code duplication. Another thing you can do is to move common code which is executed in all cases to after the `if .. elsif...end if`. In this case -- the bottom 10 lines of each clause that you have shown seem to be *identical* in both cases.

Comment: The bottom 10 lines are indeed identical in all cases. I tried to make a sub for those 10 lines but then the variables are empty since that sub doesn't know what the values of these variables are.

Comment: Move them to the bottom then -- or make a sub which has a lot of parameters. Alternatively. Pass all the needed values as a single variant -- package them with `Array()`.

Comment: Another idea for your code is to use a `select case` on the un-split `LineFromFile` rather than `if ... elseif .. end if` cascade. For that matter -- switch on `LineFromFile` and pass it as the parameter to a sub. The sub can do the splitting.

Comment: Could you post a quick example on how I should pass the values with `Array()` or on how I should use the `select case`. Sorry I'm quite new to VBA.

Comment: Alright, I'll see if I can make it work in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written some psuedo code to get you going. None of this is tested, but it will put you on the right track I hope.

First I would create a class for your booking information, lets say we named it clsBooking

```
Public BookingDate As Date
Public CancellationDate As Date
'other properties
```

Then read your line into the class:

```
Dim oBooking As New clsBooking

oBooking.BookingDate = LineItems(0)
oBooking.CacellationDate = LineItems(1)
```

Create a sub to set your values:

```
Private Sub SetValues(cells As Range, lastRow As Integer, Booking As clsBooking)

    cells("A" & lastRow).Value = Booking.BookingDate

End Sub
```

Rewrite your if to call the sub

```
if (Booking.BookingClass = "EL" And Booking.PointOfSale = "ES" etc..) Then
    Accept = "Yes"

    cells = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model").Range("B33") + BookedPax
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    call SetValues(cells, LastRow, oBooking)
end if
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out right now and will let you know if it works.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to create the class for `clsBooking` and where to put the first two steps? Do I place them somewhere else or do I replace the `Dim`s with the `Public`s in the `Sub Inlezen()` itself?

Comment: - Right click on the VBA project and select Insert Class Module, and step 1 will go here, step 2 will replace the Dim's for your current variables

Comment: How do I name the class? `Sub clsBooking()` or something else?

Comment: In the class properties change the (Name) to clsBooking (if you don't see the properties window press F4)

Comment: Compile error: ByRef-argument types don't match. Error is at `LastRow` of `call SetValues(cells, LastRow, oBooking)`

Comment: How is LastRow declared? You can also take the SetValues call out and debug and make sure all the variables are being set properly

Comment: `Dim LastRow As Long` in `Sub Inlezen()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133149/discussion-between-kevin-and-stan).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, at the place where you are pasting the line items:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS")
    ' copy the line items in the same order
    .Range(.Cells(LastRow, 1), .Cells(LastRow, UBound(LineItems)+1)).Value = LineItems

   ' insert the "zero" cell at 3rd position
   .Cells(LastRow, 3).Insert xlToRight
   .Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = 0
End With
```

p.s. you dont need to copy the line items to intermediate variables. Code will be very much shortened.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a User Defined Type (`UDT`), which is sort of a `Class` but with much less overhead and quite suitable to hold data (while classes can also provide methods)

for instance you could define this UDT at the top of your module:

```
Type MyData
    BookingDate As Date
    CancellationDate As Date
    BookedPax As Long
    BookingClass As String
    PointOfSale As String
    Origin As String
    Destination As String
End Type
```

then your main code would be:

```
Sub Inlezen()
    Dim FilePath As String

    Dim readData As MyData

    Dim Accept As String
    Dim row_number As Long

    Dim InputFile As String
    Dim LineItems  As Variant
    Dim Dummy1 As String, LineFromFile As String

    Dim PrijsWs As Worksheet, BoekingenWs As Worksheet, ModelWs As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set PrijsWs = Sheets("PrijsKlasses")
        Set BoekingenWs = Sheets("Boekingen FCO-AMS")
        Set ModelWs = Sheets("Model")
    End With

    InputFile = "PathToFile"
    Open InputFile For Input As #1
    row_number = 0
    Line Input #1, Dummy1

    Do Until EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")

        With readData
            .BookingDate = LineItems(0)
            .CancellationDate = LineItems(1)
            .BookedPax = LineItems(2)
            .BookingClass = LineItems(3)
            .PointOfSale = LineItems(4)
            .Origin = LineItems(5)
            .Destination = LineItems(6)

            If (.PointOfSale = "ES" And .Origin = "FCO" And .Destination = "AMS" And .CancellationDate = "" And ModelWs.Range("B65") < (ModelWs.Range("B15") + ModelWs.Range("B73"))) Then

                Select Case True
                    Case .BookingClass = "EL" And PrijsWs.Range("D2") > PrijsWs.Range("G2")
                        WriteValues Accept, ModelWs.Range("B33"), BoekingenWs, readData

                    Case .BookingClass = "EH" And PrijsWs.Range("D3") > PrijsWs.Range("G2")
                        WriteValues Accept, ModelWs.Range("c33"), BoekingenWs, readData

                End Select

            End If

        End With    

    Loop
End Sub
```

exploiting this little sub:

```
Sub WriteValues(Accept As String, modelTarget As Range, BoekingenWs As Worksheet, readData As MyData)
    Dim arr(0 To 7)  As Variant

    Accept = "Yes"
    With readData
        modelTarget.value = modelTarget.value + .BookedPax
        arr(0) = .BookingDate
        arr(1) = .CancellationDate
        arr(2) = .BookedPax
        arr(4) = .BookingClass
        arr(5) = .PointOfSale
        arr(6) = .Origin
        arr(7) = .Destination
    End With
    BoekingenWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 8) = arr
End Sub
```